# Destroying a networked projectile and creating a client side visual for all clients in Unity?

Tags: unity, networking, unity-networking

I'm making a **shooter** in **Unity** with **UNET**, and of course I handle **projectile** (like arrows) **collision** on the **server**.

The arrows are **Networked rigidbodies** with NetworkBehaviours, and I would like to **spawn a Non-networked**, **eye candy** like client side prefab at the collision point.

**Current solution:**

```
protected override void OnServerFixedUpdate()
{
    var distanceSincePreviousFrame = Vector3.Distance(positionAtPreviousFrame, rb.position);
    Collider collider;
    Vector3 impactPoint;
    if(CheckForImpactInNextFrame(distanceSincePreviousFrame, out collider, out impactPoint))
    {
        transform.position = impactPoint;
        DoImpactEffect(collider);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
        NetworkServer.Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    positionAtPreviousFrame = rb.position;
}
void OnDestroy()
{
    var go = Instantiate(ClientSidePrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);
}
```

- The rigidbody flies on the **server** (rigidbody synced), and **CheckForImpactNextFrame** checks collision by **raycasting**. (needed so projectiles won't go through things due to simulation errors).
- If it **collides**, then it does its impact effect, then **destroys itself on the network**.
- **Clients** instantiate a client side, **non networked prefab for visuals** when the networked projectile is destroyed.

At the **server side this works well**, "client side arrow" is instantiated at the impact position,

but at **clients**, it's instantiated at **its previous position**, because the `transform.position = impactPoint;` in the `if` isn't synced before it is destroyed on the clients.

***How could I make those client side visuals appear at the correct position?***

Could I call a "force sync" before destroying?

I can't call an RpcCreateVisuals(position) method, because the entity may be destroyed on the client when the Rpc message arrives. (because the destroy message was faster.)

I could call an "always alive" object's Rpc, like a ProjectileManager's method, and I think that it will always arrive, because destroying the projectile has no effect on it. But it feels hacky, non OOP. Doesn't it?

How should I solve this solution? What is the common approach for this problem?

**The same problem described by someone else:** https://answers.unity.com/questions/1636182/client-objects-not-traveling-same-distance-as-on-s.html

Maybe I could disable them, and subscribe them to a **"GarbageCollector"** system, which destroys them only after a **delay**? Is this a well designed solution?